# Resize image in div tag when broser resize

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
<div id="banner">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gallery/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gallery/js/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gallery/js/flashgallery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.flashgallery('gallery/gallery.swf', 'gallery/config.xml',{ width:'100%', height:'100%', background: 'transparent'});
    </script>
</div>
```

Can somebody help me to resize image in div tag it is displayed using jquery.flassgallery from last one day I am trying for this please if anybody gives me mail I will mail the code

Comment: What image? I see a `div`, `<script>` and Flash only.

Answer (score 0):

try:

http://api.jquery.com/resize/

```
$(window).resize(function() {
     $('#banner').width(/* do somthing */).height(/* do something */);
});
```

Comment: Ya i am trying but its div getting separated from screen. Sorry i am new to PHP and have tried with all these functions.